# changing title in php on refresh using cookies

Tags: php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo ("<p><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td><i>$row[3]</i></td><td><a href=\"delete.php?time=$row[2]&user=$row[0]&pass=$row[1]\"><center>[x]</center></a></td></p>");
        echo "</tr>";
        $x++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "*No Accounts*";
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['amountx'])) {
        if ($_COOKIE['amountx'] < $x) {
            $x = $x - $_COOKIE['amountx'];
            echo "<title>'New Logs - ($x)'</title>";
        }
        else if ($_COOKIE['amountx'] == $x) {
            echo "<title>'Logs (0)'</title>";
        }
        else {
        setcookie("amountx", $x, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
        }
    }
    else {
        setcookie("amountx", $x, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
    }
```

The title never updates but the cookie is saved.  This was in the while loop but I took it out and it still saves the cookie amount. But I can't get it to display the new title even after refreshing every 5 seconds via meta-refresh. How can I update the title?

Comment: Is 'Logs (0)' getting displayed, or just the wrong ($x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the structure of your code, it appears that you're printing HTML in the `<body>` tag before you're attempting to echo a different `<title>` tag.

You can't have a `<title>` tag anywhere but within the `<head>` element.

Move your `<title>` code to take effect within the `<head>` element, and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the top `<title>Page title</title>` at the top of my page now it works properly thanks guys.

Comment: I wasn't aware that using `<title>` anywhere but in the `<head>` element would actually work.. Can you post the HTML output of your script?

Comment: It is still invalid HTML. TITLE can't go in the BODY.